# manual lens distortion fix using vertex shader

Tags: glsl, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Need help with manual lens distortion fix using  vertex shader.

I would like to add lens distortion fix using vertex shader as available here

https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/TangoWithCardboardExperiments/Assets/Cardboard/Distortion/CardboardDistortion.cginc

Since I didnt use UNITY engine,I need to know how to calculate the five constant use in the function.

```
float4x4  _Undistortion;
float     _MaxRadSq;
float     _NearClip;
float4x4  _RealProjection;
float4x4  _FixProjection;
```

i would be appreciated if anyone could point me to some infos or explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: No progress since 7 months?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of how you use that shader program.
I'm not familiar with Unity Shaders either, but it seems like those variables starts with underscore are called shader properties.

Search this repository with "Shader.SetGlobal" or the variable name and I'm pretty sure you will find other variables as well.

https://github.com/googlearchive/tango-examples-unity/blob/039b3d6a3d05d4fd86e0754690d61a4690aeb5a9/TangoWithCardboardExperiments/Assets/Cardboard/Scripts/CardboardEye.cs